# Stress in words like confluence, influence, finance - noun vs verb

Tags: american-english, word-stress

I'm looking for a right way to stress words ending in -fluence in American English. There should be a change of stress depending on whether it's used a noun or verb. Also, in "finance" I stress the 1st syllable as a noun, but 2nd as a verb - am I right?

Comment: Wikipedia has [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun#List) of "Initial-stress-derived_nouns" (where the "original" verb form had stress on the *second* syllable, but when used as a *noun*, the stress moves to the first syllable)... *absent · abstract · accent · access · addict · address · affect · affix · alloy · ally · annex · assay · attribute · augment · belay · bombard · combat · combine · commune · compact · complex · composite · compost · compound · compress · concert · conduct · confect · confine(s) · conflict · conscript[ · conserve · consist ...*

Comment: Confluence isn't a verb.

Comment: I thought influence was always stressed on the first syllable.

Comment: Stress is not a foolproof test for nounhood vs verbhood. Many people put slight stress on the first syllable in both usages.

Comment: I bet they put that slight stress because they are not sure how to use it correctly. E.g. I have heard in'fluence a number of times.

Answer (score 1):

The word **finance** can have stress either on the first syllable or second, whether it's used as a verb or a noun.  I happen to work in that field and I stress the first syllable unless I'm trying to impress someone, in which case I use the second.  Stressing the second syllable sounds fancy almost to the point of being supercilious.

**Influence** has the first syllable stressed, always, regardless of whether it is used as a noun or verb.

**Confluence** is an uncommon word to the point that most people won't know it (except because of context) but the first syllable is stressed there too. I wouldn't be surprised if people mispronounced it.  I've never spoken the word aloud.

I don't know what other words you might consider "similar" to these but stressing the first syllable is a good guess in the US.

Comment: No offence, but the speech of people who work in Finance can't be used as a standard of (American) English.

Comment: None taken, but what are you saying? I said people pronounce it both ways, with stressing the second syllable being much less common in ordinary speech.  Are you saying no one stresses the second or that everyone does?